# Teechart .net Color conversion

Tags: c#, colors, rgb, teechart

I need to apply color to teechart axis using System.drawing.Color Object

Code is

```
//chartData.ChartAxesArray[iAxis].AxisTitleColor is System.drawing.Color Object

//objAxis.Title.Brush.Color is ChartFont.Color

  objAxis.Title.Brush.Color = chartData.ChartAxesArray[iAxis].AxisTitleColor;
```

This code not work as per expectation for color which are not named one or known one

Comment: What type of object `AxisTitleColor` returns?

Comment: What color are you trying to apply? I'm confused given your current code...

Comment: color whose RGB is R=0 G=255 B=128 I have Object of System.drawing.Color but it will not work. It shows blank instead of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being tChart1 an Steema.TeeChart.TChart object, with some series and values on it, you should be able to change the axis font color as I do here with the bottom axis:

```
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Font.Color = Color.Green;
```

However, I'm not sure if you are trying to set a brush color to the labels. Then, note the labels rectangle is transparent by default, so you should do something as below:

```
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Transparent = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Brush.Color = Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: when I assign color like ColorObj = Color.FromAgrb(27,81,174,83); ColorObj is hold color which is not named,known. tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Brush.Color = ColorObj; Then label color is shown as transparent

Comment: The following seems to work fine for me here:

   (new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar(tChart1.Chart)).FillSampleValues();
            Color ColorObj = Color.FromArgb(27,81,174,83);
            tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Transparent = false;
            tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Brush.Color = ColorObj;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
chartData.ChartAxesArray[iAxis].AxisTitleColor =
                               System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00FF80");

// 00FF80 = R=0 G=255 B=128
```

See that you have `objAxis.Title.Brush.Color` in the code you provided above. Shouldn't it be: `objAxis.Title.Font.Color` ?

Comment: I will assign it but for some colors it is not working. Say color whose is RGB is R=0 G=255 B=128

Comment: If it works for some colors and not this particular one, then maybe there's a bug with the chart control... 00FF80 is GREEN as you can see here: http://drpeterjones.com/colorcalc/

Comment: Still I have a problem? I have System.Drawing.Color Object I will fetch RGB values and make Color again but It is not added to objAxis.Title.Font.Color where objAxis is Steema chart object of class Axis.

Comment: when I assign color like ColorObj = Color.FromAgrb(27,81,174,83); ColorObj is hold color which is not named,known. tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Font.Color = ColorObj; Then label color is shown as transparent